# array to string in yaml with bindings to variables

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create azure pipeline and one part of it is using task AzureResourceGroupDeployment, which takes in overrideParameters as string in format: '-key value'

I would like to combine multiple parameters and use the yaml template for multiple projects so this part needs to come from combination of azure variable group value and list of keys to call those values.

basically I have an array:

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

and I like to convert it to string:

```
"-foo fooValue -bar barValue"
```

**foo** and **bar** are keys.

**fooValue** and **barValue** are from variable group mapped with same keyname foo and bar.

I know there is a [Each-expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword) in yaml, but not sure how to use it combine array to single string as variable.

I've tried to make powershell script too but it doesn't return $-signs for yaml to parse later.

part of yaml file:

```
parameters:
  varGroup: '' # variable group
  overrideParamKeys: [] # list of keys to put in arm. example: ['foo', 'bar'] converts to '-foo $(foo) -bar $(bar)'

stages:

- stage: 'deploy_${{ parameters.environment }}'
  displayName: ${{ parameters.environment }}
  variables:
  - group: '${{ parameters.varGroup }}' # use variable groupo
  - name: armOverrideParamValues
    value: ''

  pool:
    name: Azure Pipelines
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'

  jobs:  
  - job: 'setup_arm_variables'
    condition: gt(length('${{ join('', parameters.overrideParamKeys) }}'), 0)
    steps:
    - pwsh: |
        Write-Host "overrideParamKeys $Env:overrideParamKeys"
        function Combine-ArmOverrideKeys {
          param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]
            $keysString
          )
          $keys = $keysString.Split(", ")
          $valString=""
          foreach($key in $keys) {
            $valString += " -$key \$($key)"
          }
          return $valString.Trim();
        }
        $armOverrideParamValues = Combine-ArmOverrideKeys -keys $Env:overrideParamKeys
        Write-Host armOverrideParamValues $armOverrideParamValues
      displayName: "Combining arm override keys to variable 'armOverrideParamValues'"
      name: armOverrideParamValues
      env:
        overrideParamKeys: ${{ join(', ', parameters.overrideParamKeys) }}

  - job: test_variables
    steps:
    - echo: variables.armOverrideParamValues $variables.armOverrideParamValues

  # ...other job with task AzureResourceGroupDeployment using overrideParameters with value from variables.armOverrideParamValues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Used the powershell script to convert string array of keys ["foo", "bar"]
to param string template "-foo ${foo} -bar ${bar}"
which will be then used in runtime to pass in the variables from variable group.
resulted armOverrideParamVals can be put in the task AzureResourceGroupDeployment inputs overrideParameters.

```
parameters:
  varGroup: '' # variable group
  overrideParamKeys: [] # list of keys to put in arm. example: ['foo', 'bar'] converts to '-foo $(foo) -bar $(bar)' Azure variable-group names are not case sensitive, arm template parameters are and start lowercase.
  environment: '' # env you are deploying to. example dev, test, prod

stages:

- stage: 'deploy_${{ parameters.environment }}'
  displayName: ${{ parameters.environment }}
  variables:
  - group: '${{ parameters.varGroup }}'
  - name: armOverrideParamValues
    value: ''

  pool:
    name: Azure Pipelines
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'

  jobs:  
  - job: 'setup_arm_variables'
    steps:
    - ${{ if eq(join('', parameters.overrideParamKeys), '') }}:
      - script: echo no overrideParamKeys
    - ${{ if not(eq(join('', parameters.overrideParamKeys), '')) }}:
    # joins overrideParamKeys to a string as -key ${key}
    # which will be converted at runtime in deployment stage to key value.
    # that will be then passed in to the armOverrideParameters of AzureResourceGroupDeployment
      - pwsh: |
          Write-Host "overrideParamKeys $Env:overrideParamKeys"
          function Combine-ArmOverrideKeys {
            param (
              [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
              [string]
              $keysString
            )
            $keys = $keysString.Split(", ")
            $valString=""
            foreach($key in $keys) {
              if($key -eq " " -or $key -eq "") {
                continue
              }
              $valString += " -$key " + '"$' + "($key)" + '"'
            }
            return $valString.Trim();
          }
          $armOverrideParamValues = Combine-ArmOverrideKeys -keys $Env:overrideParamKeys
          Write-Host armOverrideParamValues $armOverrideParamValues # for debug
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=armOverrideParamValues;isOutput=true]$armOverrideParamValues"
        displayName: "Combining arm override keys to variable 'armOverrideParamValues'"
        name: combineArmOverrideKeys
        env:
          overrideParamKeys: ${{ join(', ', parameters.overrideParamKeys) }}

  - deployment: 'deploy_arm'
    displayName: 'Deploy ARM Templates: ${{parameters.armFilePath}}'
    ${{ if not(eq(join('', parameters.overrideParamKeys), '')) }}:
      dependsOn: ['setup_arm_variables']
    variables:
      # gets the parameter template which is in format "-key ${key}"
      ${{ if not(eq(join('', parameters.overrideParamKeys), '')) }}:
        armOverrideParamVals: $[dependencies.setup_arm_variables.outputs['combineArmOverrideKeys.armOverrideParamValues']]
      ${{ if eq(join('', parameters.overrideParamKeys), '') }}:
        armOverrideParamVals: ''
    # rest of the deployment
```